# InvalidOperationException was unhandled c#

Tags: c#

Anyone here knows about c#
Please help me, i can not find my error in here.

```
if (weather != "Data not found")
        {
            richTextBoxWeatherDetails.Clear();

            XmlSerializer result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Weather.CurrentWeather));
            var w = (Weather.CurrentWeather)result.Deserialize(new StringReader(weather));

            for (int i = 0; i < w.ItemsElementName.Length; i++)
            {
                richTextBoxWeatherDetails.Text += w.ItemsElementName[i] + ": " +w.Items[i] + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBoxWeatherDetails.Clear();
            richTextBoxWeatherDetails.Text = "Data Not Found!";
        }
```

This one is a kind of web service, i wanna check the weather in some city of the countries, it should be show data not found when i choose the city that doesn't have info but it always errors.
It works fine when i choose the city that have the info.
Can anyone help me??
[image]

Comment: As it says in exception: the `weather` variable seems to have no valid XML code as content.

Comment: You can see in the locals window that it has the value Data Not Found. The problem is with the string coparison. Posted an answer. Please try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing weather variable like:

```
if(weather != "Data not found")
```

C# String comparisons are case sensitive by default. You need a case insensitive comparison.

Change it to

```
if(string.Compare(weather, "data not found", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate if you could mark.